# Javascript array object to comma separated single line array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a response from my api that returns an object that look like this.

```
{
    "global.edit": "Edit"
},
{
    "global.add": "Add"
},
{
    "lang.english": "English"
},
{
    "lang.french": "French"
},
{
    "menu.localGroups": "Label's groups"
},
{
    "menu.locals": "Labels"
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to convert to a separated comma array.

```
const MY_NEW_LOCALS_HERE = {
    "global.edit": "Edit",
    "global.add": "Add",
    "lang.english": "English",
    "lang.french": "French",
    "menu.localGroups": "Label's groups",
    "menu.locals": "Labels"
}
```

So I can add loaded locals to React-Intl.

```
this.setState({
    localMessage: {
        ...this.state.localMessage,
        MY_NEW_LOCALS_HERE,
    }
})
```

I spent hours trying to figure it out but I just can't.

Any help on how to achieve this?

If I use `OBJECT.join(',')` I get an [object Object],[object Object] array.

Comment: Your object is an array, so you need to use the `reduce()` method.

Comment: Your object is array and array is object.

Comment: @Taplar, do you have a quick example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use deconstruction with the reduce method to put all the keys into a single object.

```js
var temp = [{
    "global.edit": "Edit"
  },
  {
    "global.add": "Add"
  },
  {
    "lang.english": "English"
  },
  {
    "lang.french": "French"
  },
  {
    "menu.localGroups": "Label's groups"
  },
  {
    "menu.locals": "Labels"
  }
];

var result = temp.reduce((r,v)=>({...r, ...v}),{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just a question : why are you adding **, {}** to the end of **result** ?  

**var result = temp.reduce((r,v)=>({...r, ...v}));** works well

Comment: @adil.hilmi The last `{}` is the initial value. `array.reduce(closure, initialValue);`

Comment: Okay it's just an optional argument to put initial value for the result. Thx @Taplar